# JS code not working in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, cloudpage

I have the following code which works fine in normal html (removing runat=server) but breaks in SFMC cloudpage.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email">
<input type="checkbox" name="phone">
<input type="checkbox" name="sms">
<input type="checkbox" name="whatsapp">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="togglecheckboxes('cn')" value="Toggle all">

<script runat="server">
var isAllCheck = false;
  function togglecheckboxes(cn){

      var cbarray = document.getElementsByName(cn);
      for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){

          cbarray[i].checked = !isAllCheck
  }   
  isAllCheck = !isAllCheck;   
}
</script>
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work in SMFC cloudpages? I want to have the last checkbox deselect the other checkboxes onclick.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t simply take any JS and run it as SSJS. Since you will be running it server side, the code will only be executed once, when the page loads. If you need to do anything which relates to capturing events happening client side (like a checkbox changing state), you should not set `runat=“server”` attribute

Comment: Understood. However, removing runat="server" still doesn't work.

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there (also this is not an SFMC specific question). Did you check e.g. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229023/how-do-i-check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-a-button-using-jquery)?